# Having problems using mysql_connect in text editor

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm currently following through some php tutorials and right now I'm learning how to connect the server to a database.

The code I've have type in so far in my text editor is:

```
<?php

$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_pass = '';

mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
?>
```

My screen is completely blank so I thought great the code has worked fine. However I thought just to check I'd mess up the code see what response I get. So I changed this:

```
$mysql_user = 'root'; to $mysql_user = 'alex';
```

I thought this would throw up an error message on my screen but it didn't, which led me to believe that my code was wrong. Or I have been setting things up wrong, because the user is 'root' not 'alex'.

Just for some information. The text editor I'm using is brackets and the code I have shown is from a file called index.php that is in a folder called databases which sits in the htdocs folder. Oh and I'm using Xampp

Comment: Find yourself another tutorial please! `mysql_` functions are deprecated and [will be removed](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7) in the next PHP release

Comment: You may want to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in conjunction with @kingkero's advice

Comment: ok thanks, any good tutorials you know, what should I be using instead of mysql_connect

Comment: Any tutorial that recommends the PDO library would be a good starting point. At least you'll know it's reasonably up-to-date. Try http://phptherightway.com/ for a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this at begin of file to show warnings:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: by default does it not show errors, is it good practice to always use that code at the start of the file

Comment: Also you can setup this in php.ini